# When syncing iphone 5, itunes hangs on backup stage

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, iphone

I have a new iPhone 5 (iOS 6.0.1) and successfully configured it with a backup of my old iPhone via iTunes on my Windows 7 PC. This basically transferred all my settings, media and apps.

I added some more music to my iTunes the next day and tried to sync my iPhone. So I plug in using the Lightning cable and click "Sync". I goes through the motions until it hits `stage 2, backing up`. Here it hangs and never gets past this stage. I left it on overnight the other day and it was in exactly the same state in the morning as I left it the night before.

I also can't seem to skip the backup stage by clicking the <kbd>x</kbd>. it just seems to freeze up for a bit when I do and then resumes the never ending backup.

Any advice on how to solve this as I literally just want to put 1 album on my iPhone and at the moment, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

Delete any old backup related to this device

1. Open finder
2. command-shift-g to open the go to folder.  Put in ~/Library  Hit go
3. Navigate to Application Support > MobileSync > Backup
4. Order by Date Modified and look for the latest folder which should be timed at the last time you did a backup.  Drag the folder out to the desktop
5. Try to resync with the phone

If it all works you'll get a new backup in the folder, delete the one on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

My phone did the same thing, I shut down my computer then turned it back on didn't work.

To solve the problem, I then held the home button and power button (of the phone) until the Apple sign came on then let go waited for it to boot up then my phone stay connected the whole time and I was able to sync my music.